# icloud - different formats of syncing

Tags: ios, synchronization, icloud

I am looking into implementing iCloud syncing into my iOS app.

Do I have to make a choice wether I need to sync just documents or key-values? or can I comine the 2??

I have reasons for both.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to make that choice. You can have save key-value data as well as documents into iCloud from within the same App.